# Тень/обводка у курсора на MacOS, можно ли убрать ее?

Tags: css, macos, cursor

На MacOS появляется тень от курсора, который был заменен на картинку белой стрелки (svg). Курсор меняется на картинку в стилях при наведении на область.
На первом скриншоте курсор с MacOS, на втором - с других платформ.

Можно ли убрать тень/обводку у курсора и как?

```
cursor: url("../../assets/pictures/svg/cursor-left.svg"), auto;
```

```
<svg width="61" height="52" viewBox="0 0 61 52" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M37 31L1 31L1 21L37 21H39.135L37.7682 19.3598L28.3149 8.01584L34.0553 1.45542L59.5583 26.4861L34.0686 50.5598L28.3149 43.9842L37.7682 32.6402L39.135 31H37Z"
          stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Так выглядит на MacOS]
[image: Так выглядит на других платформах]

Извините за качество первого скриншота.

Comment: как минимум понадобится сам код

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , добавлен код

Comment: код самой svg конечно же

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, готово

Comment: а если добавить эту svg не как курсор, что-то изменится?  речь про десктопный мак?

Comment: Или я слепой или там не видно ни какой тени

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да, речь про десктопы и лэптопы. Предлагаете, добавить, как объект? И двигать его в зависимости от положения курсора? Тоже идея, но мне важен вопрос оптимизации. Вопрос вот в чем был: тень от курсора - маковская фича? Чинить ее не обязательно, главное понять, можно ли это как-то убрать

Comment: @etterwin вам виднее, у меня нет мака чтобы что-то Вам еще подсказать =)

Comment: Фича маковская и скорее всего на неё не повлиять. Для тех, кто не видит тени, вот белый курсор-стрелка от ТС на белом фоне: http://work.arsenty.ru/screenshots/Screenshot%202019-05-14%20at%2010.50.30.png

Comment: Проверил форматы SVG / PNG / ICO - разницы нет. CUR не заработал.